# Getting 3G instead of 4G (LTE)

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, modem, 3g, usb-modem

I've got a **Sierra Wireless Airprime MC7354** module, supplying a cellular communication to my x86.

By default, on module boot, it searches for an LTE network connection, and if fails - it falls back to 3G.

Though I'm supplied with several Sim cards, from different providers, all are LTE compatible (works great on my phone) - **I can only get a 3G network (no LTE)**.

Ideas anyone?

Comment: What does your provider have to say?

Comment: Are you within LTE coverage?

Comment: You need LTE coverage/signal there. It will not work otherwise even if you have full signal with 3G or 2G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the MC7354 supports only specified LTE bands in specific regions and is marketed for Americas region with LTE bands: B2, B4, B5, B13, B17, B25.

My provider was not supplying LTE connection in one of the above bands. I had to switch to another model that works on an LTE band that my provider provides.

For a list of suitable LTE bands provided by Sierra Wireless:

- https://www.sierrawireless.com/products-and-solutions/embedded-solutions/networking-modules/#/mcseriesembeddedmodules

For lists of LTE networks and frequency bands around the world:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_LTE_networks
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTE_frequency_bands

Comment: This isn't really an answer... You are just stating the capabilities of the hotspot, not how this "answer" applies to this situation. I am assuming you are not in North America, but you should give a more complete answer.

Comment: Much better... upvoting answer.